# How to specify FUN used in by( ) or related apply( ) functions

Tags: r, callback, statistics

In a `by()` function, I will use `cor` (correlation) to be the `FUN` there. However, I'd like to setup `use="complete.obs"` too.

I don't know how to pass this argument in the `FUN = cor` part.

For example,

```
by(data, INDICES=list(data$Age), FUN=cor)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

probably

```
by(data, INDICES=list(data$Age), FUN=cor, use = "complete.obs")
```

will work.

the arguments to `by` are passed to `FUN`.

Answer (score 7):

If you start looking around at various R help files for functions like `by`, you may start to notice a curious 'argument' popping up over and over again: `...`. You're going to see an ellipsis listed along with all the other arguments to a function.

This is actually an argument itself. It will collect any other arguments you pass and hand them off to subsequent functions called later. The documentation will usually tell you what function these arguments will be handed to.

In this case, in `?by` we see this:

```
...  further arguments to FUN.
```

This means that any *other* arguments you pass to `by` that don't match the ones listed will be handed off to the function you pass to `FUN`.

Another common instance can be found in `plot`, where the documentation only lists two specific arguments, `x` and `y`. Then there's the `...` which gathers up anything else you pass to `plot` and hands it off to methods or to `par` to set graphical parameter settings.

So in @kohske's example, `use = "complete.obs"` will be automatically passed on the `cor`, since it doesn't match any of the other arguments for `by`.

Answer (score 2):

@kohske and @joran give equivalent answers showing built in features of `by` (which are also present in `apply` and the entire `plyr` family) for passing additional arguments to the supplied function since this is a common application/problem.  @Tomas also shows another way to specify an anonymous function which is just a function that calls the "real" function with certain parameters fixed.  Fixing parameters to a function call (to effectively make a function with fewer arguments) is a common approach, especially in functional approaches to programming; in that context it is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) or [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

```
library("functional")
by(data, INDICES=list(data$Age), FUN=Curry(cor, use = "complete.obs"))
```

This approach can be used when one function does not use `...` to "pass along" arguments, and you want to indicate the only reason that an anonymous function is needed is to specify certain arguments.

Comment: interesting.... basically another way how to write the second possibility in my post. Or does it have some significant advantage over it?

Comment: @TomasT. The advantages are syntactic and aesthetic.  Using `Curry` indicates that all you are doing is specifying arguments.  With a full anonymous function, you can do much more, but that requires more inspection to see what is actually being done. Additionally, with an anonymous function, you (may) need to specify all the other arguments if for no other reason to pass them along (although that could be done using `...`).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have 2 possibilities:

1) specify the arguments in the calling function (`tapply()` or `by()` in this case). This also works even if the key argument to `fun()` is not the first one:

```
fun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) { ... } # just to see how fun() looks like
tapply(var1, var2, fun, arg1 = something, arg3 = something2) 
    # arg2 will be filled by tapply
```

2) you may write your wrapper function (sometimes this is needed):

```
tapply(var1, var2, function (x) { fun(something, x, something2) })
```